# Tras instalar el plugin @ionic-native/local-notifications da error de compilación

Tags: ionic, cordova, plugin, compilacion

Hace unos días que estoy intentando desarrollar un trackeo de posición, para ello estoy usando el plugin 'cordova-plugin-geolocation' para obtener la posicion y el plugin 'cordova-plugin-background-mode' pero únicamente he conseguido que se ejecute durante unos pocos minutos, aun teniendo la aplicación configurada 'sin restrinciones' de batería.

Por lo que he decidido crear una notificación silenciosa para despertar la aplicación cuando esté en segundo plano.

Tras instalar el plugin @ionic-native/local-notifications da error de compilación. El cual muestro más abajo.

He probado a cambiar el gradle a diferentes versiones, a ejecutar 'ionic repair'.

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este error?

**`npm i @ionic-native/local-notifications`**

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/animations@7.2.16 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.16 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@5.2.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file-transfer@4.20.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/header-color@4.20.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/http@4.20.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-signature-pad@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-signature-pad@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-signaturepad@2.11.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-signaturepad@2.11.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @ionic-native/local-notifications@5.36.0
added 2 packages from 1 contributor, removed 7 packages, updated 2 packages and audited 1851 packages in 9.302s

37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 356 vulnerabilities (11 low, 121 moderate, 167 high, 57 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

**`ionic cordova build android --prod`**

```
ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --prod --target cordova --platform android
[12:49:39]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4 
[12:49:39]  build prod started ... 
[12:49:39]  clean started ... 
[12:49:39]  clean finished in 24 ms 
[12:49:39]  copy started ...
[12:49:40]  deeplinks started ... 
[12:49:41]  deeplinks finished in 1.23 s 
[12:49:41]  ngc started ... 
[12:50:06]  ngc finished in 25.61 s 
[12:50:06]  preprocess started ... 
[12:50:06]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[12:50:06]  webpack started ...
[12:50:07]  copy finished in 27.34 s 
[12:50:53]  webpack finished in 46.61 s 
[12:50:53]  uglify started ... 
[12:50:53]  sass started ... 
[12:50:57]  sass finished in 3.74 s 
[12:50:57]  cleancss started ... 
[12:50:59]  cleancss finished in 2.65 s 
[12:51:39]  uglify finished in 46.17 s 
[12:51:39]  postprocess started ... 
[12:51:39]  postprocess finished in 66 ms 
[12:51:39]  lint started ... 
[12:51:39]  build prod finished in 119.90 s
[12:51:46]  lint finished in 6.41 s
> cordova.cmd build android
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'properties-parser'
Require stack:
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\platforms\platforms.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\plugman.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova-lib\cordova-lib.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova\src\help.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js
- C:\_programacion\cordova\demoapp\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
Unhandled error. ('The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.')
(node:15956) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'android' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Gracias